# How to do in game text chat in Assassins creed 3?

Tags: assassins-creed-3, ubisoft-connect

Earlier I used to play MW3 multiplayer. There we have a very simple way to chat. Just press T and write, everyone can see that. Press Y and write only your team mates can see that. But in Assassin's Creed 3 I can't find any similar way to chat. How do I use in-game text chat?

I play Assassin's Creed multiplayer on uPlay.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to perform in-game text chat. If you're on PC, you can activate the UPlay Overlay using Shift+F2, and chat with your friends. Of course, that means that the players you are playing against have to be your friends. (go and friend everyone, right now! :P)

Alternatively you can just use the in-game voice chat. I haven't encountered anyone who used it though, even in the prequel AC:Revelations.

Personally I think this is a huge problem with playing cooperatively on Multiplayer, esp. when people start doing the darndest things in Wolfpack. On the other hand, if there were in-game chat, you can imagine tensions would be running pretty high.

Comment: Completely agreed.  Can I add you in uPlay? :P Tell me your ID.

Comment: id: ionParallax. disclaimer, i only login on random days, heh. :)